# Python 3 variable in request causing 404?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, urllib, python-3.4

I've got two lists, one a list of dates the other a list of hours and I'm scanning a website looking for content.

```
date = ['1','2','3']
hour = ['1','2','3']
```

I've written the following `while` / `for` to loop through the dates and hours and open all the combinations:

```
datetotry = 0  
while (datetotry < len(date)):
    for i in range(len(hour)):              
        print ('https://www.website.org/backups/backup_2004-09-'+date[datetotry]+'_'+hour[i]+".sql")
        html = opener.open('https://www.website.org/backups/backup_2004-09-'+date[datetotry]+'_'+hour[i]+'.sql').read()
datetotry += 1
```

When the console prints the url it looks okay with the variables being replaced with the numbers from the list.

But its possibly not replacing the variables in the actual url request.

The code was stopping due to a 404 error but I think I handled that with the info I found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#wrapping-it-up

The first part of the 404 error was showing the

```
date[datetotry]+'_'+hour[i]+
```

section, instead of the items from the list like when its printing to console.

Does this mean I have to do something like `urllib.parse.urlencode` to actually replace the variables?

I imported the libraries mentioned in the article and changed code to:

```
 from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
 from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

while (datetotry < len(date)):
for I in range(len(hour)):              
    HTML = Request('https://www.website.org/backups/backup_2004-09-'+date[datetotry]+'_'+hour[i]+'.sql')
    try:
        response = urlopen(html)
    except URLError as e:
        print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
        print('Error code: ', e.code)
    except URLError as e:
        print('We failed to reach a server.')
        print('Reason: ', e.reason)
    else:
```

So the code actually runs, not stopping due to 404 being returned. What is the best way to see what its actually requesting and do I have to do some kind of encoding? New to programming especially Python 3.

Comment: Shouldn't the day and hour be zero-padded?

Comment: Can you show us a *valid, working* URL?

Comment: If you're not limited to the stdlib, there's the requests library